# How to write a .cfg file with ":" instead of "=" in python

Tags: python, string, config

I'm using python3 ConfigParser, my code is

```
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg_file = open('./config.cfg', 'w')
conf.set(None, 'a', '0')
conf.write(cfg_file)
cfg_file.close()
```

I expected the result to be `a : 0` in the config.cfg file. However, I got `a = 0`. Is there a way to replace "=" with ":"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delimiters parameters to [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser):

> When `delimiters' is given, it will be used as the set of substrings
> that divide keys from values.

```
conf = configparser.ConfigParser(delimiters=':')
```

Result:

```
[DEFAULT]
a : 0
```